# Google Mapsengine responding insufficient permissions to service account

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-oauth, google-maps-engine

I am trying to create tables for a google map in the maps engine. I have added the service account to the access list in the mapsengine admin panel for the map and gave it "can edit" permissions. I also gave it edit permissions in the developer console for the project.

this is where I am sending off for the access token which is sending back a token:

```
    var googleapis = require('googleapis');
    function connect() {
        var authClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
            '216755859529-1s2o9qofhd9ea65ang9clpd1936ldfcr@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
            '../bin/googleoauth2.pem',
            'notasecret',
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mapsengine'],
            // User to impersonate (leave empty if no impersonation needed)
            ''
        );

        authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
             if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             return;
        }
         else {
             console.log(tokens);
        }

        googleapis.discover('mapsengine', 'v1').execute(function (err, client) {
             if (err) {
                 console.log('Problem during the client discovery.', err);
                 return;
             }
             createNewTable();
             client.mapsengine.tables.create(mapengine_table_body).withAuthClient(authClient).execute(function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log(response);
                return;
            }
        });

    });
  });
}
```

This is where I am creating the table and sending it:

```
function createNewTable() {

   mapengine_table_body = {
  "projectId": projectID,
  "name": "World Famous Mountains",
  "description": "A partial list of famous mountains in the world.",
  "draftAccessList": "Map Editors",
  "tags": [
    "mountain",
    "high places"
  ],
  "schema": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "geometry",
        "type": "points"
      },
      {
        "name": "mountain_name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "height",
        "type": "integer"
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
function start() {

    'use strict';
    var pck, program;

    pck = require('../package.json');
    program = require('commander');

    program
        .version(pck.version)
        .option('-r, --run', 'Run')
        .parse(process.argv);

    console.log('running:');
         if (program.run) {
         connect();
    }
}
```

The ProjectId I am getting from the url when viewing the project. I have looked through as much documentation as I can find, but I haven't been able to figure this one out. Thanks.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing (and where)?  And what libraries are you using for the authentication & request steps?  Your code doesn't look like the [Google JS library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs), have you tried them?

Comment: @MarkMcDonald I actually changed the code to use the google node library. I am still getting the error in the cli when I log the response. I am able to GET and log the response and it will list the projects or maps that I have previously made, but it will not let me create a table. I am getting a "Insufficient permissions for this action" I am editing my original post to show the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Without your error response I can't give you an exact answer, but here are a couple of pointers.

1. Check the contents of `err` in the execute block. The API will return something in `err.errors` that should explain what the problem is, if it's occurring on the API side.
2. It's not clear what the scope of the `mapengine_table_body` variable is, try logging it right in the `connect()` call right after calling `createNewTable()` to make sure you have the actual data.
3. The third argument in the `googleapis.auth.JWT` constructor (at least according to [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/jwt.js)) is **not** the key password, it's an alternative way to provide the actual key inline (as opposed to using the file location in argument #2).
4. Project IDs in Maps Engine may look like large numbers but treating them as large numbers in JavaScript will very likely result in rounding, meaning that you give the API a different number than is in your code. To prevent this, make sure your project ID is "quoted", so that its treated as a string.

Hopefully something here helps!  If not, please share the output from suggestion #1.